# How can I make localized a non-localized model in Larvel Backpack?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-backpack, laravel-translatable, laravel-models

I have a non-localized model: Article with the following properties: *id*, *title*, *description*; and I want to localize *title* and *description*.

I have seen in the Laravel Backpack documentation that CRUDs can manage localized models using *spatie/laravel-translatable*, which uses JSON fields for each property [Translatable models and multi-language CRUDs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-update#translatable-models-and-multi-language-cruds).

I think it's a good way to manage new localized models but I can't find a way to pass my Article model to a localized-version without rewriting a big part of the existing software.

There is a good practice I'm missing to do it?

Comment: Are you currently using backpack?

Comment: Yes, currently I have my backend done with backpack

Answer (score 0):

If you already using `Backpack` then using `spatie/laravel-translatable` is best option.
You can make your `Article` model like below to make as translatable mode.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\SpatieTranslatable\HasTranslations; //you need to add

class Article extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasTranslations; //you need to add

     /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | GLOBAL VARIABLES
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */

    protected $table = 'articles';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description'];
    protected $translatable = ['title', 'description']; //you need to add
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I already have a whole application (not the backoffice) that works with that data. I was wondering if there is a best practice to pass from a non-localized model to a localized model without rewriting the application (not the backoffice).